# Запятая, тире или двоеточие?

Tags: пунктуация, бсп

Но выпить чай и вправду стоит, тебе станет лучше. 
Какой знак препинания требует данное бессоюзное предложение?

Comment: Лучше выпить ча**ю**, если это не уговоры выпить уже налитый чай.

Comment: @Alex_ander, спасибо, вы правы...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Но выпить чай и вправду стоит, тебе станет лучше.***

Стиль **разговорный**, в таких случаях обычно ставится **запятая.**

**Тире** используется для обозначения взаимообусловленности предложений, **двоеточие** говорит о том, что причинное значение имеет второе предложение.

**Запятая просто распространяет тему,** обозначая последовательность в изложении мыслей.

Comment: спасибо за ответ. А использование тире в данном предложении не будет считаться ошибкой?

Comment: Нет, ошибкой не будет. Если нужно ставить знаки строго по школьным правилам, то объяснение такое. Второе предложение имеет значение причины. В основном варианте ставится двоеточие, но тире в этом случае часто заменяет двоеточие. Но вообще говоря, тире лучше смотрится в таком предложении: Выпьешь чаю - тебе станет лучше. Здесь разделительное тире, значение условия: если выпьешь, то станет лучше.

Comment: не по школьным правилам. Ну например, если я пишу книгу, как лучше оформить? Знаю, что по правилам требуется двоеточие, но как-то хочется тире поставить, только не знаю, правильно так будет или нет? Если вы советуете, то я не сомневаюсь, что так будет правильно...

Comment: Книга - это замечательно, я очень люблю авторов книг. Правила позволяют ставить в этом случае любой знак. Как его выбрать? Прочитайте текст. Вам хочется подчеркнуть  паузу между предложениями? Тогда ставьте тире. Можно также проверить графику: какой вариант выглядит красивее, логичнее и вписывается в контекст. Таким образом,  даже действуя строго в рамках  правил, автор имеет возможность свободного выбора, что очень важно.

Comment: как вы меня обрадовали фразой, что автор имеет возможность свободного выбора, что очень важно. Тогда я выберу тире. Спасибо вам - вы всегда так помогаете и так хорошо разъясняете всё.